# How do I get windows registry property values using a PowerShell script run through a .Net PowerShell object?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I am using the following PowerShell script to return information about apps installed on a PC:

```
Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
```

When I run this script in the Windows Powershell ISE, I see something like this for results:

> ```
> Hive: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
> ```
>
> Name                           Property
>
> ----                           -------- Connection Manager             SystemComponent : 1
> DirectDrawEx
> Docker Desktop                 DisplayIcon     : C:\Program
> Files\Docker\Docker\Docker Desktop Installer.exe
> DisplayName     : Docker Desktop
> DisplayVersion  : 2.1.0.4
> Version         : 39773
> InstallLocation : C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker
> NoModify        : 1
> NoRepair        : 1
> Publisher       : Docker Inc.
> ChannelName     : stable
> ChannelUrl      : https://download.docker.com/win/stable/appcast.xml
> UninstallString : "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Docker Desktop
> Installer.exe" uninstall

I am calling the script from a C# .Net application as follows:

```
using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
{
   ps.Runspace = p_runspace;
   ps.AddScript("Get-ChildItem ""HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall""");
   IEnumerable<PSObject> commandOutput = ps.Invoke();
}
```

How do I programmatically get access in C# to the properties returned when I run the script (Publisher, DisplayName, DisplayVersion) returned when I run the script in the ISE?
I examined the properties on the PSObject in my app, they do not match up with the ISE.

Thanks, JohnB

Comment: Why not just query them directly in C#?

Comment: itsme86 - We're using PowerShell scripts and running them on remote endpoints through our .Net app. Not an option to use C# libraries directly.

Comment: From a command line use : REG QUERY KeyName.  See: https://www.computerhope.com/reg.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects returned from PowerShell when invoked using [`PowerShell.Invoke()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.invoke?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0#System_Management_Automation_PowerShell_Invoke) don't don't actually have all of the same members at the top level of the object, a bit of PowerShell "magic" makes it work that way from within a PowerShell session.

If you want a property value you need to inspect the `Properties` property of the returned [`PSObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psobject.properties?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0):

```cs
foreach(PSObject obj in commandOutput) {
  Object val = obj.Properties['PropertyName'].Value
}
```

where `PropertyName` is the name of the property you want.